# Send command to Amazon EC2 instance using Boto3 in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am able to create an instance from an image on Amazon EC2 using boto3 using the following code:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name = 'eu-west-2')
instance = ec2.run_instances(
           ImageId='ami-011c936382e4e2g9c',
           MinCount=1,
           MaxCount=1,
           InstanceType = 't2.micro',
           SecurityGroupIds= ['sg-0c08ad7b130e3hf3',],)
id = str(instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'])
```

This works fine, but I then wish to send a simple command to the instance which will execute a python script stored on the instance. From what I can gather, boto3 has the AWS command line functionality built in and so I shouldn't have to SSH to the instance; I should be able to send a command through boto3. However I'm strugging to do this, after trying different variations of the below code:

```
client = boto3.client('ssm',region_name='eu-west-2')
commands = ['echo "hello world" > hello.txt'] #this would be replaced by the command to execute the python script
instance_id = [id] #id being the instance id established from above
response = client.send_command(DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
                               Parameters= 'commands':commands},
                               InstanceIds=instance_id,)
```

I'm aware that it takes time for the server to fire up etc but this isn't the problem. I have executed this second chunk of code after a large delay when I know the server is indeed ready to go.

As mentioned, I think this might be to do with the pem file that I normally need to use in order to putty/ssh into an instance as this isn't configured anywhere into my code. Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Do you use, Amazon Linux as your base ami? If not then most likely the SSM agent is  not installed in your instance

Comment: Cheers for getting back so quick, this is the error: "botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occured (InvalidInstance) when calling the send comman operation" I am now just hard-coding the instance id to the instance I know is running. (so ignore the first section of code). Have checked and the instance id 100% matches up. Also it's worth mentioning that the instance is indeed Amazon Linux.

Comment: If you go to Systems Manager in the management console, does the new instance appear in the list of target instances? The Amazon Linux AMI includes the SSM Agent, which will "call back" to AWS from the instance so that it can be reached from SSM. If the instance is showing in the console, it should be possible to send the commands. Try doing it manually in the console first.